# Davening without a Minyan - Hallel Pesach night

Tags: minhag, passover, hallel

There are those that say Hallel, Pesach night after Maariv. This year when it looks like, due to COVID-19, we will still not be Davening with a Minyan Pesach night, does one who is Davening without a Minyan still say Hallel after Maariv, before the Seder?